# Trying to create openssl for windows 7 but getting problems:

Tags: openssl, gnu-make

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32>dir

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin

07/24/2018  10:22 PM    <DIR>          .
07/24/2018  10:22 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/16/2004  01:37 PM           898,048 libiconv2.dll
05/06/2005  12:52 PM           103,424 libintl3.dll
11/24/2006  06:28 PM           175,104 make.exe
               3 File(s)      1,176,576 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  135,022,383,104 bytes free
```

openssl is at `C:\Program Files` and environmental variable.

```
C:\Program Files\openssl>gcc makefile
makefile: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help. It would be great if a .msi file existed for openssl.

Comment: "It would be great if a .msi file existed for openssl.". The [OpenSSL Wiki Binaries page](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries) mentions a few places where you could look for Windows binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments to `make` are targets to be built, not the makefile itself.  To run a specific makefile, use the `-f` option:

```
make -f C:\usr\local\src\openssl\makefile
```

However, most makefiles expect to run in the directory of the build or the sources, so you should do this:

```
cd C:\usr\local\src\openssl\makefile
make
```

When no makefile is specified, make will try a built-in list of makefile names (`GNUMakefile`, `makefile`, `Makefile`).